# Server error on WordPress hosted on Azure with ClearDb

Tags: mysql, wordpress, azure, cleardb

I'm hosting my personal WordPress blog on Azure (with the free ClearDb Mercury plan).

It works fine for few months until last week, I'm getting **"The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."** errors.

Thought the error was due to IIS hibernate mode that put a site to sleep mode when it's not active for certain amount of time (say 20 minutes). I tried running a schedule job from Azure to access my blog [www.JeeShenLee.com](http://www.jeeshenlee.com) and below the attached are the results.

You can see many errors.
[image]

Comment: Running out of server resources? This is a common occurrence when a site gets more popular, or if a site grows (due to uploaded assets, pages, posts, etc), and the server can't handle it. Do you have any way to see detailed process information on that server?